# AJAX call is made to wrong url. What gives?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, post, telerik

I'm having trouble with an AJAX POST.  I'm defining where I want the AJAX call to be posted, but it's posting elsewhere.  Please help.

I'm using an MVC Telerik Grid.  It probalby doesn't matter if you aren't familiar with it.  I'm following the example at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingbatch

From that example, Important pieces to this Grid puzzle include:

```
.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
```

Also from that example, defining the url for the AJAX call:

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("_SelectContactsBatchEditing", "Ajax", new {FirstName = @ViewData["FirstName"], LastName = @ViewData["LastName"]})
        .Update("_SaveContactsBatchEditing", "Ajax", new {FirstName = @ViewData["FirstName"], LastName = @ViewData["LastName"]})
    )
```

For both `Select()` and `Update()` methods, the first parameter is the Action and the second parameter is the Controller.  I have a third optional parameter which contains the other data to send back in the post.

My grid is Master/Detail.  I've taken out the Detail portion and I'm still having the issue.  I've giving you my entire grid.  For now please let's focus on the Master portion.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<ContactView>()
    .Name("ContactsGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound<int>(c => c.Id).Width(65).ReadOnly();
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.FirstName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.LastName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.Phone).Width(120);
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.Street).Width(200);
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.City).Width(100);
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.Province).Width(50).Title("Prov");
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.PostalCode).Width(80).Title("PC");
        columns.Bound<string>(c => c.Email).Width(100);
        columns.Bound<bool>(c => c.OkToContact).Width(40).Title("Ok")
            .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' name='OkToContact' <#=OkToContact? checked='checked' : '' #> />");
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Delete();
        }).Width(100);
    })
    .DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
            Html.Telerik().Grid<DonationView>()
                .Name("Donations_<#= Id #>")
                .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
            .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DefaultDataItem(new DonationView(){Description = "Internal Cause"}))
                .DataKeys(d => d.Add<int>(a => a.Id).RouteKey("Id"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(65).ReadOnly();
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Description).Width(400);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Amount).Width(80);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Date).Format("{0:d}");
                })
                /*.ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("cause_onRowDataBound"))*/
                .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                    .Select("_SelectDonationsHierarchyBatchEditing", "Ajax", new { ContactID = "<#= Id #>" })
                    .Update("_SaveDonationsHierarchyBatchEditing", "Ajax", new {ContactID = "<#= Id #>"})
                )
                .Sortable()
                .ToolBar(commands => {
                    commands.Insert();
                    commands.SubmitChanges();
                })
                /*.Filterable()*/
                .ToHtmlString()
    ))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("_SelectContactsBatchEditing", "Ajax", new {FirstName = @ViewData["FirstName"], LastName = @ViewData["LastName"]})
        .Update("_SaveContactsBatchEditing", "Ajax", new {FirstName = @ViewData["FirstName"], LastName = @ViewData["LastName"]})
    )
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
    //.Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(25))
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataKeys(d => d.Add<int>(a => a.Id).RouteKey("Id"))
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(500))
    .ToolBar(commands => {
        commands.Insert();
        commands.SubmitChanges();
    })
    //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 1200px" } ) 
    .Sortable()
      )
```

My `Select()` method calls correctly, however my `Update()` method does not.  It simply posts to the same page the grid resides on.  I had this working but didn't bother to check in (stupid), and broke it a few days later.  No amount of Ctrl+Z has helped me.

Here is the action in my Ajax Controller.  Details removed since they don't matter.  The method just isn't getting called.

```
 [GridAction]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult _SaveContactsBatchEditing([Bind(Prefix = "inserted")]IEnumerable<ContactView> insertedContacts,
            [Bind(Prefix = "updated")]IEnumerable<ContactView> updatedContacts,
            [Bind(Prefix = "deleted")]IEnumerable<ContactView> deletedContacts, string FirstName, string LastName)
        {
            ISession session = SessionManager.OpenSession();
            ContactProvider cp = new ContactProvider(session);
            if (insertedContacts != null)
            {
                //stuff
            }
            if (updatedContacts != null)
            {
                //stuff
            }
            if (deletedContacts != null)
            {
                //stuff
            }

            IList<ContactView> Contacts = new List<ContactView>();
            ContactViewProvider Provider = new ContactViewProvider(SessionManager.OpenSession());
            Contacts = Provider.GetContactsByName(FirstName, LastName);
            //return View(new GridModel(Contacts));
            return new LargeJsonResult
            {
                MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue,
                JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new GridModel<ContactView>
                {
                    Data = Contacts
                }
            };
        }
```

When I click the Save button in my grid's toolbar, I can use firebug to see the `Select()` method makes the proper AJAX call but the `Update()` method doesn't:  (See https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPCS6.png)

In this image the first post url corresponds with the values passed into my `Select()` method.  The second post url does not correspond with my `Update()` method.

What's going on here?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is nothing wrong with what I did.  The MVC project somehow became messed up.

I created a throwaway project to try to reproduced the issue but I couldn't - the throwaway was working.  So I deleted the MVC project in my solution and copied the pieces into the new project one by one and sure enough, it works.  I have no idea how it became discombopulated in the first place but at least the issue is rectified.  For anyone having the same issue, I suggest you try this!